# PostGIS: Update child geometries based on parent

Tags: postgis, polygon, leaflet, topology, leaflet-draw

I'm using Leaflet and postgis in a case where using Leaflet draw plugin I draw a polygon first like this[image]

Now, I draw a line which cuts the polygon and using line and polygon geometry, based on postgis `ST_Split` function, I store the geometry of splitted polygons and consider them as children of previous polygon like this.

[image]

Coming towards the issue, I want to update the geometries where If I increase/decrease the length or width of black polygon (the parent), red polygons (the children) lengths should also increase/decrease. Is there any combination of techniques and/or `PostGIS` functions which can help me in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you also store the line that is used to split the parent, you could recreate the children when the parent is changed.

This could be done thru a trigger that reacts to updates on the parent spatial feature.

Comment: 1- What if the height of line is not enough to split the polygon (parent) again as the height of polygon has been increased during editing.
2- Else, if not the above case, splitting the parent again couldn't make me to update exactly the same child. As I can't remove previous children and insert new. In my case I've to update them.

Comment: How do you create the split line in the first place? How do you make sure it is long enough at that time? How you considered only modifying the children and then merge these back into the patent?

Comment: In order to create children of Parent, I give line tool to draw line and instruction to touch the polygon boundary at exactly two places. If line touches boundary at exactly two places, result of split will exactly be two. If that is the case, I store the output result as children otherwise generates error. By third question, do you mean that modify the children and then union of them to store as parent?

Comment: Yes, it might be easier for you to combining the children into an updated parent than to splitting a parent into updated children. For the combine operation you don't need any split line. This does of course depend on the "business rules" - whether it's even possible to go from the children to the parent